# To create an object (of some class) in a listener

Tags: oop, event-handling, dm-script

I'm creating a script and have troubles.

Is it possible to create an object (of some class) from within a listener?
I tried it but I get an error: ``class not found''.

I want to do something like:

```
class ONE {
    class_ONE_code
}

class TWO {
    object o = alloc(ONE)
}
```

I need this to create a new listener when I execute another listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wish to do is certainly possible.  Most likely you have a syntax error in your code.  For example, your implementation of class TWO is invalid since a member variable like "o" cannot be initialized in the member declaration section of the class code.  This can only be done within a class method, as illustrated in the example code below.

```
class One
{
    void DoClassOneAction(Object self)
    {
        OKDialog("Class One action executed.");
    }
}

class Two
{
    Object oneInstance;

    void DoClassTwoAction(Object self)
    {
        if (!oneInstance.ScriptObjectIsValid())
            oneInstance = Alloc(One);
        oneInstance.DoClassOneAction();
    }
}

void main()
{
    Object twoInstance = Alloc(Two);
    twoInstance.DoClassTwoAction();
}

main();
```

Note that the coding requirements for DM script classes differ somewhat from those of other languages that support objects.  You may want to review details in the Scripting > Objects section of the DM on-line help (accessed via Help > Search… menu item).