# To create an object (of some class) in a listener (part II)

Tags: oop, events, dm-script

I did some [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014758/to-create-an-object-of-some-class-in-a-listener) about this, and the response was good, but trying an example with listeners I have a mistake:

Is possible that someone will test this code and explain why it does not find the EVENT_ONE class?

```
void functionONE(){
    result("\n dentro de la FUNCION ONE")
}


class EVENT_ONE : object{

    void accionONE(object self){
        result("\n dentro de accionONE()")
    }

    EVENT_ONE(object self) result("\n EVENT_ONE creado")
    ~EVENT_ONE(object self) result("\n EVENT_ONE destruido")
}

class KEY_TWO : object{

    number evento
    object o

    void almacenaEventoTWO(object self, number pulsacion) evento = pulsacion

    number accionTWO(object self, ImageDisplay disp, object keydesc){
        number control=0

        Result("\n key:"+keydesc.GetKeyDescriptor())
        Result(" ("+keydesc.GetDescription()+")") 

        If ( keydesc.MatchesKeyDescriptor("esc")){
            result("\n has pulsado escape")
            control=1
            disp.ImageDisplayRemoveKeyHandler(evento)

            o = alloc(EVENT_ONE)
            //number idObjecto2 = disp.ImageDisplayAddEventListener( o,     "accionONE" )
            o.accionONE()

        }
        return control
    }

    KEY_TWO(object self) result("\n KEY_TWO creado")
    ~KEY_TWO(object self) result("\n KEY_TWO destruido")
}


void main(){
    image img = getFrontImage()
    showimage(img)
    imageDisplay imgDisp = img.imageGetImageDisplay(0)

    object controlFinal = Alloc(KEY_TWO)
    number idControlFinal = imgDisp.ImageDisplayAddKeyHandler( controlFinal,     "accionTWO" )
    controlFinal.almacenaEventoTWO(idControlFinal)
}
main()
```

It is necessary put any image in desktop for the key-listener (class KEY_TWO) works. At this class, when I press any key, print it, and if you press "esc", destroy the key listener and find the mistake ("class EVENT_ONE not found").

On the other hand, Is it possible call "functionONE" from class KEY_TWO or EVENT_ONE??

Sorry by disturb but I don't find the mistake.

Thanks and Regards. Sergio

Comment: Hi Sergio, great you've found your way here to StackOverflow DM-script! On this site it is general policy to *not* write unnecessary text (like apologies, thanks etc.) in the actual questions/answers but rather into comments. The questions/answers should contain directly relevant information only. This helps others to more easily and faster find/read/understand things. Also, if you find an answer "correct" or "most useful" to you, please "accept" it by clicking the little check-icon under the up&down-vote arrows. This gives both you and the person who wrote the answer "reputation" on site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class definitions in an executed DM script file are only valid during the execution of that script.  Your main function is completely finished executing by the time a user enters key strokes for your listener, and so the class definition for EVENT_ONE is no longer valid.  Your code will work if you split off the implementations of the EVENT_ONE and KEY_TWO classes into a separate file and then install that file as a script library.  This way, the class definitions remain valid throughout the life of the DM session.

Comment: While correct, the need to install as a library makes it hard to develop the code. I would advise against this practice.

Answer (score 1):

Mike is right about the script code staying "available" only as long as held by the script parser. However, a better solution to your problem is to allocate the 2nd object in the *constructor* of you KEY_TWO class (or in an initialization method called in the main script.) At this stage, the code is still available. So your script above becomes:

```
class EVENT_ONE : object{

    void accionONE(object self){
        result("\n dentro de accionONE()")
    }

    EVENT_ONE(object self) result("\n EVENT_ONE creado")
    ~EVENT_ONE(object self) result("\n EVENT_ONE destruido")
}

class KEY_TWO : object{

    number evento
    object o

    void almacenaEventoTWO(object self, number pulsacion){
        evento = pulsacion
    }

    number accionTWO(object self, ImageDisplay disp, object keydesc){
        number control=0

        Result("\n key:"+keydesc.GetKeyDescriptor())
        Result(" ("+keydesc.GetDescription()+")") 

        If ( keydesc.MatchesKeyDescriptor("esc")){
            result("\n has pulsado escape")
            control=1
            disp.ImageDisplayRemoveKeyHandler(evento)

            //o = alloc(EVENT_ONE)  // DO NOT ALLOCATE HERE - THE CODE IS NO LONGER AVAILABLE

            o.accionONE()
        }
        return control
    }

    KEY_TWO(object self) 
    {
        result("\n KEY_TWO creado")
        o = alloc(EVENT_ONE) // ALLOCATE HERE - THE CODE IS STILL AVAILABLE
    }
    ~KEY_TWO(object self) result("\n KEY_TWO destruido")

    // ALTERNATIVELY: Have a Init-method and alloacte here. This method is called (from the main script)
    // while all code is still available. Return the object self just to be able to "pipe-line" the Init call
    object Init(object self) {
        // o = alloc(EVENT_ONE) // ALTERNATIVE ALLOCATE HERE - THE CODE IS STILL AVAILABLE
        return self
    }
}


void main(){
    image img = getFrontImage()
    showimage(img)
    imageDisplay imgDisp = img.imageGetImageDisplay(0)

    object controlFinal = Alloc(KEY_TWO).Init() // Call INIT method
    number idControlFinal = imgDisp.ImageDisplayAddKeyHandler( controlFinal,     "accionTWO" )
    controlFinal.almacenaEventoTWO(idControlFinal)
}
main()
```

---

As for the global function: I would advise you to **avoid** global methods and variables altogether. The idea of OOC is to have all code encapsulated in the object.

---

Finally, there is also the option to allocate all objects in the main method and pass them on as a parameter to other objects. This allows f.e. to have the identical object be accessed by multiple other objects. One warning though: Be careful that objects don't hold "each other" or they can not be released from memory. (This can be avoided by using ObjectIDs and the command `GetScriptObjectFromID`. See the F1 help documentation on *weak referencing* in the chapter *scripting->Objects* for further information.)

An example of such a construct:

```
class CCommon
{
    number v
    CCommon( object self ) { result("Created CCommon ID:"+self.ScriptObjectGetID()+"\n"); }
    ~CCommon( object self ) { result("Destructed CCommon ID:"+self.ScriptObjectGetID()+"\n"); }
    number GetV(object self ) { return v; }
    object SetV(object self, number val){ v=val; return self; }
}

class COne
{
    object co
    object init( object self, object common ) { co=common; return self; }
    object double( object self ) { co.SetV( co.GetV() * 2 ); return self; }
}

class CTwo
{
    object co
    object init( object self, object common ) { co=common; return self; }
    object AddOne( object self ) { co.SetV( co.GetV() + 1 ); return self; }
}

void main()
{
    object c = Alloc(CCommon).SetV(0)
    result("\n Initial:" + c.GetV() + "\n" )
    object o1 = Alloc(COne).Init(c)
    object o2 = Alloc(CTwo).Init(c)
    for (number i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        o2.AddOne()
        result(" After +1: " + c.GetV() + "\n" )
        o1.Double()
        result(" After x2: " + c.GetV() + "\n" )
    }
}
main()
```

Comment: Hi! It was just what I needed. Both solutions work very good. Many thanks!!

Comment: The solutions suggested by @BmyGuest certainly yield a more self-contained solution.  I agree that these are cleaner and more maintainable approaches.